How to Use FutureBuilder with a future that needs a BuildContext Without Recomputing the Future on Every Build in Flutter?
I'm working with Flutter and trying to use a FutureBuilder to fetch data based on a state managed by the Provider package. The challenge I'm facing is that my Future depends on a state that I can access through Provider.of<MyData>(context).
Here's the problem:

I need to initialize the Future in the constructor of my widget, but since the constructor does not have access to the build context, I can't retrieve the state from the provider.
If I try to create the Future inside the build method, it gets recomputed every time the widget rebuilds, which is not ideal for performance.

My Current Approach:
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<DataType> future;

  MyWidget() : future = fetchData(); // This can't access context

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final myData = Provider.of<MyData>(context); // Need to use myData here

    // Creating the Future here causes it to recompute on every build
    final future = fetchDataBasedOn(myData);

    return FutureBuilder<DataType>(
      future: future,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Build your widget based on snapshot
      },
    );
  }
}

My Question:
How can I manage the Future in a way that it only computes once, and still be able to access the provider's state? Is there a recommended pattern for achieving this with Flutter's FutureBuilder and Provider?
Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Could you check this https://flutterdata.dev/articles/future-async-called-multiple-times/

You can use initState, initState is used to initialize the Future only once when the widget is created.
example :
Future<DataType>? future;

void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((callback) {
      final data = Provider.of<YourProvider>(context);
      setState(() {
        future = fetchData(data);
      });
    });
  }

then use the future in the FutureBuilder that you use.

how do you access context from initState?

 class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  Future<DataType> future;

@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
super.didChangeDependencies();
// Initialize the future in 

didChangeDependencies
    future = fetchDataBasedOn(Provider.of<MyData>(context, listen: false));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<DataType>(
      future: future,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        } else {
          return Text('Data: ${snapshot.data}');
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

You may use like this, I hope this may help you.

initState doesn't have a build context from my understanding. how to do Provider.of<MyData>(context, listen: false)?

Yes, so use didchangedependency, it will work

    > you can use init() method to manage future and  it compute only once and also you can access provider state.
    
- example for understanding..
    
     /// Create getter and future variable
        Demo get demoData => Provider.of(context, listen: false);
        late Future<dynamic> future;
        
    /// call getData() method 
        void initState() {
         super.initState();
         getData();
       }
    
     /// in this method you can initialized futureVariable and also manage provider state and you can use future in futureBuilder alse
        getData() async {
          future = await fetchData(demoData);
        }


how do you access the provider state in init()? init doesn't have a build context from my understanding

please see my previous answer i can modified for better understanding
